# Cursor as in parameter - refactoring a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have many functions similiar to this one:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE REP_HELPER1 (myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE, rep_table IN OUT rep_table_T) IS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



CURSOR myCUR1 IS SELECT myField1,
                        myField2,
                        myField3,
                        myField4,
                        myField5,
                        myField6,
                        myField7,
                        myField8,
                        myField9,
                        myField10,
                        myField11,
                        myField12,
                        myField13,
                        myField14,
                        myField15,
                        myField16,
                        myField17,
                        myField18,
                        myField19,
                        myField20,
                        myField21,
                        myField22,
                        myField23,
                        myField24,
                        myField25,
                        myField26,
                        myField27,
                        myField28,
                        myField29,
                        myField30,
                        myField31
                   FROM myTable;
BEGIN 
    -- I wish to move the part below to different procedure
    OPEN myCUR1;
    FETCH myCUR1 INTO rep_table(myIdx).day1,  rep_table(myIdx).day2,  rep_table(myIdx).day3,  rep_table(myIdx).day4,  rep_table(myIdx).day5,
                      rep_table(myIdx).day6,  rep_table(myIdx).day7,  rep_table(myIdx).day8,  rep_table(myIdx).day9,  rep_table(myIdx).day10,
                      rep_table(myIdx).day11, rep_table(myIdx).day12, rep_table(myIdx).day13, rep_table(myIdx).day14, rep_table(myIdx).day15,
                      rep_table(myIdx).day16, rep_table(myIdx).day17, rep_table(myIdx).day18, rep_table(myIdx).day19, rep_table(myIdx).day20,
                      rep_table(myIdx).day21, rep_table(myIdx).day22, rep_table(myIdx).day23, rep_table(myIdx).day24, rep_table(myIdx).day25,
                      rep_table(myIdx).day26, rep_table(myIdx).day27, rep_table(myIdx).day28, rep_table(myIdx).day29, rep_table(myIdx).day30,
                      rep_table(myIdx).day31;
    CLOSE myCUR1;
END  REP_HELPER1;
```

I wish to do the part from  `open myCUR;`  to  `close myCUR;` in a separate univesral procedure. As I have many functions like the above and the cursor is always different. So I would like to have one procedure which would do the open,fetch, close part :

```
PROCEDURE PB_HELPER_READ_INTO_DAYS(nIndex IN BINARY_INTEGER, myCUR by reference, rep_table IN OUT rep_table_T)
```

Is it possible to to it in plsql?

EDIT:
Based on yours clues I wrote it like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROCEDURE REP_HELPER1 (myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE, rep_table IN OUT rep_table_T) IS
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       
myCUR1 SYS_REFCURSOR; 
        
BEGIN 
            
         OPEN myCUR1 FOR SELECT myField1,
                                myField2,
                                myField3,
                                myField4,
                                myField5,
                                myField6,
                                myField7,
                                myField8,
                                myField9,
                                myField10,
                                myField11,
                                myField12,
                                myField13,
                                myField14,
                                myField15,
                                myField16,
                                myField17,
                                myField18,
                                myField19,
                                myField20,
                                myField21,
                                myField22,
                                myField23,
                                myField24,
                                myField25,
                                myField26,
                                myField27,
                                myField28,
                                myField29,
                                myField30,
                                myField31
                           FROM myTable;
                 MY_READ(myIdx , myCUR1, rep_table) 
    END  REP_HELPER1; 
    
PROCEDURE MY_READ(myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR, rep_table IN OUT rep_table_T) IS
        
    BEGIN
     
            FETCH cur INTO rep_table(myIdx).day1,  rep_table(myIdx).day2,  rep_table(myIdx).day3,  rep_table(myIdx).day4,  rep_table(myIdx).day5,
                                  rep_table(myIdx).day6,  rep_table(myIdx).day7,  rep_table(myIdx).day8,  rep_table(myIdx).day9,  rep_table(myIdx).day10,
                                  rep_table(myIdx).day11, rep_table(myIdx).day12, rep_table(myIdx).day13, rep_table(myIdx).day14, rep_table(myIdx).day15,
                                  rep_table(myIdx).day16, rep_table(myIdx).day17, rep_table(myIdx).day18, rep_table(myIdx).day19, rep_table(myIdx).day20,
                                  rep_table(myIdx).day21, rep_table(myIdx).day22, rep_table(myIdx).day23, rep_table(myIdx).day24, rep_table(myIdx).day25,
                                  rep_table(myIdx).day26, rep_table(myIdx).day27, rep_table(myIdx).day28, rep_table(myIdx).day29, rep_table(myIdx).day30,
                                  rep_table(myIdx).day31;
                CLOSE cur;
 END MY_READ;
```

Comment: Do all the functions use `rep_table`, and do all the cursors have columns that exactly match it?

Comment: All cursors have colums of type varchar and all cursors have alsways 31 columns.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you could have a function or procedure that accepted a ref cursor and populated a `rep_table`.

Answer (score 2):

Option which would work is to create a package, declare cursor *globally* and use it in any procedure you want. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test is
  2    procedure p1;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test is
  2    cursor c1 is select * from dept;
  3    c1r c1%rowtype;
  4
  5
  6    procedure p1 is
  7    begin
  8      open  c1;
  9      fetch c1 into c1r;
 10      close c1;
 11    end p1;
 12  end;
 13  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

---

This won't work: declaring a cursor in one procedure and working with it in another:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test is
  2    procedure p1;
  3    procedure p2;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test is
  2    procedure p1 is
  3      cursor c1 is select * from dept;
  4      c1r c1%rowtype;
  5    begin
  6      null;
  7    end p1;
  8
  9
 10    procedure p2 is
 11    begin
 12      open  c1;
 13      fetch c1 into p1.c1r;
 14      close c1;
 15    end p2;
 16  end;
 17  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/11    PLS-00201: identifier 'C1' must be declared
13/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/11    PLS-00201: identifier 'C1' must be declared
14/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/11    PLS-00201: identifier 'C1' must be declared
SQL>
```

Also, you can't reference it using the "owner" procedure's prefix:

```
SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test is
  2    procedure p1 is
  3      cursor c1 is select * from dept;
  4      c1r c1%rowtype;
  5    begin
  6      null;
  7    end p1;
  8
  9
 10    procedure p2 is
 11    begin
 12      open  p1.c1;
 13      fetch p1.c1 into p1.c1r;
 14      close p1.c1;
 15    end p2;
 16  end;
 17  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/14    PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'P1' reference is out of scope
13/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/11    PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'P1' reference is out of scope
14/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
14/11    PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'P1' reference is out of scope
SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put only `FETCH` and `CLOSE` in a different procedure. Would be this (when you have only one OUT parameter, then I prefer a `FUNCTION`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REP_HELPER (myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS    
   myCur SYS_REFCURSOR;    
BEGIN

   OPEN myCur FOR
   SELECT myField1, ...
   FROM myTable;
   RETURN myCur;

END REP_HELPER;
```

And use it like this:

```
DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 
    
    cur := REP_HELPER(...);    
    FETCH cur INTO ...

    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

A more advanced solution would be dynamic SQL with [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm) Package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REP_HELPER(myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER IS

  curid NUMBER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN

  sql_stmt := 'SELECT myField1, ... FROM myTable';
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(curid, sql_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  RETURN  curid;

END REP_HELPER;

DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    curid NUMBER;
    ret INTEGER;
BEGIN 
    
    curid := REP_HELPER(...);    
    ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);
   -- Switch from DBMS_SQL to native dynamic SQL
    cur := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(curid);
    FETCH cur INTO ...

    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REP_HELPER(curid IN OUT NUMBER, myIdx IN BINARY_INTEGER, from_d IN DATE) IS

  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN

  sql_stmt := 'SELECT myField1, ... FROM myTable';
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(curid, sql_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

END REP_HELPER;


DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    curid NUMBER;
    ret INTEGER;
BEGIN 
    
    curid NUMBER := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    REP_HELPER(curid, ...);    
    ret := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);
   -- Switch from DBMS_SQL to native dynamic SQL
    cur := DBMS_SQL.TO_REFCURSOR(curid);
    FETCH cur INTO ...

    CLOSE cur;
END;
```

But I think this would be an overkill.

**Update:**

You can compose the SQL string also dynamically, e.g.:

```
sql_stmt := 'SELECT ';
FOR i IN 1..31 LOOP
   sql_stmt := sql_stmt  || 'myField'||i||',';
END LOOP;
sql_stmt := REGEXP_REPLACE(sql_stmt, ',$');
sql_stmt := sql_stmt  || ' FROM '||table_name;
sql_stmt := sql_stmt  || ' WHERE the_date = :d';    
OPEN cur FOR sql_stmt USING from_d;
```

Comment: I have many different cursors. What is same is pattern (same filelds types and same amount of fields in all cursors). I don't need one global static cursor.

Comment: Do you see any global static cursor in my code?

Comment: I have many differen `REP_HELPER` functions. `REP_HELPER1`,.... `REP_HELPER55`. All `REP_HELPER` functions have different cursors inside.  You call `curid := REP_HELPER(...); `which is not what I want as I can define cursor only once...

Comment: Then I would suggest to create only one function/procedure with one more parameter. Otherwise you need dynamic SQL: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REP_HELPER' || 5 ||'(...)' INTO cur`;

Comment: I'm not getting what you mean with one function with one more parameter...

Comment: Write just one function `REP_HELPER` - the composed queries you determine by input parameters.

Comment: No, I need one rep_helper pro cursor as the cursors are very long.

Comment: Why should it depend on the size of the cursor? You can open a cursor also from string, i.e. `OPEN myCur FOR 'SELECT ...'`. The string you could compose dynamically. With `DBMS_SQL` you have **all** freedom, but more coding work and I would assume in your case it would be an overkill.

Comment: Consider to return the SQL string rather than the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the cursor in a package spec outside of any procedure or function. Then use that cursor virtually any where a cursor is valid (except as a reference cursor). Includes any procedure/function within the package or any standalone procedure/function, and even an anonymous block. Just be sure to reference as `package_name.cursor_name` anywhere outside of the package. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd833f38b2764278ac2cb3df9055e64b))

```
create or replace package pkg_test is
  cursor c_dept is select * from dept;
  
  procedure p1;
  procedure p2;  
end pkg_test;
/
```

This makes maintenance of the cursor quite easy since there is only one definition, so only one place of maintenance.

Comment: I have many different cursors. What is same is pattern (same filelds types and same amount of fields).